# julia @printf changes my variable

Tags: julia

I find difficult to format numbers with Julia :

```
b = 1.111111
bb = @printf "test : %5.2f" b
bb

test :  1.11
```

That is fine.

```
using PyPlot 
annotate(@printf "test : %5.2f" b, xy=[1;1])

test : 
type: non-boolean (Array{Bool,1}) used in boolean context
while loading In[16], in expression starting on line 2
```

That I don't understand since I expect the result of @printf to be a String. So if someone can explain me how I should do what would be

```
"test : %5.2f" % b
```

in Python.

And to conclude, here is the weird thing :

```
b
1
```

b has been cast to an Int. Would you call that a bug?

I use Julia 0.3.2 with Jupyter 3.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macro parsing (particularly within the context of a function call) is a little finicky.  You can see how Julia parsed this simply by quoting it:

```
julia> :(annotate(@printf "test : %5.2f" b, xy=[1;1]))
:(annotate(@printf "test : %5.2f" (b,xy) = [1,1]))
```

As you can see, the macro is "greedier" than function arguments.  The entire `b, xy=[1;1]` part is taken as the only argument to the `@printf` macro.  This explains why the value of `b` changes — the `=` has changed contexts from denoting a keyword argument to being a general tuple assignment!

I highly recommend using the function-like syntax for macros when using them within more complicated expressions like this:

```
annotate(@sprintf("test : %5.2f", b), xy=[1;1])
```

And, finally, note that I've changed `@printf` to `@sprintf`.  The former returns `nothing` and simply prints the value out, whereas the latter returns a string that you can pass to functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the trick to see how Julia parses a macro.